# Python increment value for dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Is there a way to do something like:

```
if key in myDict:
   if innerKey in myDict[key].innerKeys:
      myDict[key].update({innerKey:getInnerValue()+1})
   else:
      myDict[key].update({innerKey:0})
```

What I want is a structure like:

```
{key1:{innerKey1:counter, InnerKey2:counter... }, key2:{innerkey3:counter}...}
```

Comment: Nested dictionaries are no different from normal dictionaries. `myDict[key]` returns just another dictionary object, you can do the exact same things with that dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `in` and `and` operators to check for the inner key in one line more succinctly. This works because the `if` statement will evaluate to `False` immediately if `key` is not in `myDict`:

```
if key in myDict and innerkey in myDict[key]:
      myDict[key][innerKey] += 1
elif key in myDict:
      myDict[key][innerKey] = 0
```

Comment: That won't work for the problem, because if a key exists but innerkey does not, then what I want is to issue an update(), whereas for the outer if() i.e. when key doesn't exist, I'd do: myDict[key][innerKey] = 0

Comment: Then I can place it in an `elif` instead!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. The syntax is a bit different, however.

```
if key in myDict:
    if innerKey in myDict[key]:
        myDict[key][innerKey] += 1
    else:
        myDict[key][innerKey] = 0
```